# Storing results of SQL Select query in a var node js

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to store the results of this select query like a "rank" chart for a game but I'm not sure if what I'm encountering is an async issue or a data-type issue or something else entirely. Any thoughts?

```
var ranksVar = [];

db.all("select * from user", function(err, rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    setValue(rows);
  }
});

function setValue(value) {
  ranksVar = value;
  console.log(ranksVar);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Jesse Please, provide more details about the module used (what is the module behind `db`), errors or a detailed goal :D. We can't really help you accurately w/ further details ^^.

Comment: @RahulSingh No error just displays as "[Object, object]"

Comment: @DataHearth db is just the connection to my sqlite database 

```
const dbconnect =require('./dbconnect.js')
```

Comment: @Jesse So you are getting the required Objeft.Just do console.log(JSON.stringify(ranksVar)) to view the ranksVar value. The JSON. stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out a useful post about using SQLite with NodeJS and it gives you the basic examples needed to understand how to use it. Here it is: [SQLite NodeJS](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/)

In your case, look under the section [data query](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/).

Here the example code:

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/chinook.db');

let sql = `SELECT DISTINCT Name name FROM playlists
           ORDER BY name`;

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    console.log(row.name);
  });
});

// close the database connection
db.close();
```

As you can see, the `rows` variable is (I guess) a special type created by the module. To get all data from it, you might want to iterate over it and push it into your array variable.

Cheers  !

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was a data type/async issue, I was trying to print a string for an undefined array.

Went back a loop and used the JSON.stringify method to display the array objects correctly.